# Converting string to ArrayList<String>

Tags: android, string, arraylist

I know it's a strange question but I need one thing: I receive a string as a result of a http operation. In reality this string contains an array of strings like this:

```
["Leon","Prova 2","TestData"]
```

Basically I want to convert this string into an ArrayList because I need it for an adapter. This is the java code:

```
public class Archivio{

    static ArrayList<String> titoli = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> art = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String response, response2 = null;
    HttpClient httpclient;
     HttpPost httppost,httppost2;
     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs,namePairs;
    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    Archivio() {

        try {

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

                    httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
                     httppost= new HttpPost("http://tripleleon.altervista.org/artiview2.php"); 
                     nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                      httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                     //Esecuzione richiesta HTTP Post e ricezione risultato operazione
                     //response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                     ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                     response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                     System.out.println("Response : " + response); 
                     httppost2= new HttpPost("http://tripleleon.altervista.org/artiview3.php"); 
                     namePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                      httppost2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                     ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler2 = new BasicResponseHandler();
                     response2 = httpclient.execute(httppost2, responseHandler2);
                     System.out.println("Response : " + response2); 

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ArrayList<String> retTitle() {
        return response;
    }


    ArrayList<String> retArt() {
        return response2;   
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not do network operations from the main thread.

Comment: as I said into another comment: this is a class made for tests. I'm using threads into the real project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with the following code (being `stringArray` the `String` that contains your "array"):

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray.substring(1, stringArray.length() - 1).replaceAll("\"", "").split(",")));
```

This will remove the first and last characters (`[` and `]` respectively) and split by the `,` character. Afterwards, convert it into an `ArrayList` using the `Arrays.asList` method.

Comment: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to ArrayList<String>"

Comment: Simply wrap it into a `new ArrayList<String>(...)` statement (updated my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the `JSONArray` and add it to `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jr = new JSONArray("string");
for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
{
   String value =(String) jr.get(i);
   list.add(value); 
}
```

But you are not using `Thread` or `Asynctask` for getting the json from the server. Do not use `StrictMode` in production stage.

Also check your minsdk in manifest  `@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })`. You have suppressed lint warning

Comment: it's a temporary class made for various tests. Of course I'm using threads in the real project ;)